# I need to convert latitude and longitude to address from rest api in to a listview

Tags: flutter

I am fetching the latitude and longitude from rest api and have to convert to address everytime when the list gets loaded, but I am getting **'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String' Flutter**. I have also **tried to add FutureBuilder**. How to solve this I am newbie to flutter.

```
 body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount:
                  _getAttendanceLog == null ? 0 : _getAttendanceLog.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final item = _getAttendanceLog[index];
                     
                   return card(
                   child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                       new Container(
                              child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                              if(item.startlattitude == 'null'|| item.startlattitude == null||item.startlongitude == 'null'|| item.startlongitude == null) ...[
                              new Text("In Location : -", style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*3),)
                               ]else ...[
                               Marquee(
                               child: Text("In Location : " + getUserLocation(item.startlattitude, item.startlongitude),style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*3),),
                               directionMarguee: DirectionMarguee.oneDirection,
                               ),SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal*3),),
                               ]
                              ],
                            ),
                         ),
                    ])
                   )
```

and I have used Geocoder also see below ======> **getUserLocation**

```
getUserLocation(startlat, startlong) async {

    final coordinates = new Coordinates(
        startlat, startlong);
    var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
        coordinates);
    finalInLocation = addresses.first;
    print(' ${finalInLocation.locality}, ${finalInLocation.adminArea},${finalInLocation.subLocality}, ${finalInLocation.subAdminArea},${finalInLocation.addressLine}, ${finalInLocation.featureName},${finalInLocation.thoroughfare}, ${finalInLocation.subThoroughfare}');
    return finalInLocation;
  }
```

I need like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are passing a `Future` to a parameter which expects a `String`.

Because you need to wait for the api to convert the lat-long to an address text, you need to use a `FutureBuilder` in the widget tree at the place where you need to display the address text inside your `itemBuilder` like this..

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getUserLocation(lat, lon),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                return Text('loading...');
              } else {
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              }
            })
```

And you will need to make your `getUserLocation` method to return a `Future<String>` like this..

```
Future<String> getUserLocation(startlat, startlong) async {
    //other code
    await //more code;
    return yourAddressString;
  }
```

Comment: Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you bro. Working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder) package to convert latlng to address list

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(1.10, 45.50);
addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

Comment: I have used it.. I need in the listview and assign converted function(lat, long) to text.

Comment: Usually this type of data comes from API end. But if you really want to do it in Android you have to go through each of the list item, and convert the coordinates to address using the Geocoder. Which is a really time consuming and resource heavy process. I would discourage you to do it this way.

Comment: Issue got solved. Btw I only show 8 items per list. Thanks for the information.